# Single Linked Lists and Time Complexity

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, time-complexity

I'm just starting my jurney with topic of Data Structures and working with some Single linked lists. I crated a two type of lists:

1. Where Nodes are added to the head of the list checking from the tail (Time complexity O(n))
2. Where Nodes are added to the head of the list checking only the head (Time complexity O(1))

I wanted to run test and check the output of my code and more or less it's correct but I noticed this weird noises and I don't know why they are there. Do you guys have any clue on that?

```py
class Node(object):
        def __init__(self, data = None):
            self.data = data
            self.next = None

        def _str_(self):
            return str(self.data)


class SonglyLinkedList_tail:
        def __init__(self):
            self.tail = None
            self.size = 0

        def append(self, data):
            node = Node(data)
            if not self.tail:
                self.tail = node
            else:
                current = node
                while current.next:
                    current = current.next
                current.next = node
            self.size += 1

class SinglyLinkedList_head:
        def __init__(self):
            self.tail = None
            self.head = None
            self.size = 0

        def append(self, data):
            node = Node(data)
            if self.head:
                self.head.next = node
                self.head = node
            else:
                self.head = node
                self.tail = node
            self.size += 1

        def iter(self):
            current = self.tail
            if current.next:
                val = current.data

                current = current.next

tail = SonglyLinkedList_tail()
head = SinglyLinkedList_head()
xes = []
yes = []
for i in range(5000):
        xes.append(i)
        list = random.sample(range(1, 100000), i)
        start_time = float(time.time())
        stop_time = float(time.time())
        for number in list:
            tail.append(number)
        stop_time = time.time()
        run_time = stop_time-start_time
        yes.append(run_time)
```

[Time complexity for O(n) algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UvwJ.png)
[Time complexity for O(1) algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS1i2.png)

EDIT:

Photo after suggested changes in algorithm 1 [First algorithm time complexity O(n^2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLd9F.png)

Answer (score 0):

I can find two mistakes in your code, that might be leading to errors.
First, inside the SinglyLinkedList_tail function's append method, you are doing current = node, which is wrong. Because the 'node' has just been created and through it you can't traverse the linked list. Variable 'current' should be initialized with 'tail'. The correct way is:

```
class SonglyLinkedList_tail:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

   def append(self, data):
       node = Node(data)
       if not self.tail:
            self.tail = node
       else:
            current = tail
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = node
       self.size += 1
```

Second, the SinglyLinkedList_head function's append method has a similar problem. It;s correct implementation can be:

```
def append(self, data):
    node = Node(data)
       if self.head:
            node.next = self.head.next
            self.head = node
       else:
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
       self.size += 1
```

Comment: Vasistha For the class SonglyLinkedList_tail you are right it makes more sense to set current as self.tail and I do this change. The output of this is funny because now Time Complexity is O(n^2) but we get rid of the noises (mostly - see Edit in my post). Theoretically, it should be O(n).

Comment: And for the second one, I think everything is okay in my code. I took the last Node in my list (the head) and linked it with my new Node (node) using the variable next. Then set the newly added node as the end of the list (by setting it as the head). In your code, you linked new node to None (because the head is not connected to anything so head.next = None) and then you set the newly added Node as the head so we get non linked list with this technic.